# Spring - creating objects with new operator using @Configurable & @Value annotations

Tags: java, spring, properties, dependency-injection, aspectj

Is it possible to use @Configurable on a class that's weaved using AspectJ and get Spring to load in values on fields/methods which are annotated with @Value?

I know its possible with @Autowired and @Resource etc... Are there any others.

e.g.

```
@Configurable
public Class MyObj{
 @Value("$(my.prop)")
 private String aField;

 public String getAField(){
   return aField;
 }
}
```

And then have something like

```
public aMethodSomewhereElse(){
   MyObj obj = new MyObj()
   assertNotNull(obj.getAField());
}
```

Are there any alternatives to being able to create `MyObj` with the `new` operator and still get spring to handle the annotations?

**--EDIT:--**

**It IS possible to do this using `new` when using @Autowired**, have a look at some Hibernate and JPA stuff with Spring and AOP... I've used this in the past to do some profiling of Java code. But I really want to use SPEL and @Value before I mock up a full example I was hoping to find the answer here. FYI - if you don't belive me the Spring Manual even says it is possible to do this, what I want to know is if its possible to use **@Value** annotations in the same scope...

> The Spring container instantiates and configures beans defined in your
>   application context. It is also possible to ask a bean factory to
>   configure a pre-existing object given the name of a bean definition
>   containing the configuration to be applied. **The spring-aspects.jar
>   contains an annotation-driven aspect that exploits this capability to
>   allow dependency injection of *any* object.**

And...

> Using the annotation on its own does nothing of course. It is the
>   AnnotationBeanConfigurerAspect in spring-aspects.jar that acts on the
>   presence of the annotation. In essence the aspect says "after
>   returning from the initialization of a new object of a type annotated
>   with @Configurable, configure the newly created object using Spring in
>   accordance with the properties of the annotation". In this context,
>   initialization refers to newly instantiated objects (e.g., ***objects
>   instantiated with the 'new' operator***) as well as to Serializable
>   objects that are undergoing deserialization (e.g., via readResolve()).

http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.0.RC2/reference/html/ch07s08.html

Cheers.

Comment: I don't think it is possible to use `new` operator and ask spring to  autowire properties. I think 1 way to solve this is to get a static reference to `applicationContext` and create a `prototype` scoped bean.

Comment: This IS possible using AspectJ and @Configurable annotation as mentioned in my question. See the spring manual: http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.0.RC2/reference/html/ch07s08.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are absolutely right - `@Autowired` fields will be wired in an `@Configurable` annotated class even outside of a Spring container, assuming that you have a AspectJ infrastructure in place.

You have noted a good catch though, `@Value` fields are processed by a Spring bean post processor(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor), which resolves the `@Value` annotated fields. It does not act on objects instantiated outside of the container though - so in short, the @Autowired fields should get wired in, but `@Value` properties will not.

Comment: Thanks @Biju I thought this might be the case. Any ideas/trickery I could use to get these objects processed by the Post Processor?

Comment: I think of a few options, one will be to inject in an `Environment` which is populated using a `@PropertySource` annotation, the second option could be to use a `<util:properties id="props"` with the properties that you want and autowire in `Properties` instance, you can then do `props.getProperty(name)` explicit calls in your code. Both these solution essentially bypass `PropertyPlaceHolderConfigurer`

Answer (score 3):

I don't think it is possible to use `new` operator and ask spring to autowire properties. I think 1 way to solve this is to get a static reference to `applicationContext` and create a prototype scoped bean.

```
@Component
public class ApplicationContextLocator {
    private static ApplicationContext applicationContext;

    public static ApplicationContext getApplicationContext() {
        return applicationContext;
    }

    public ApplicationContextLocator() {
        super();
    }

    @Autowired
    public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext applicationContext) throws BeansException {
        ApplicationContextLocator.applicationContext = applicationContext;
    }

}

@Scope(BeanDefinition.SCOPE_PROTOTYPE)
@Component
public class MyObj {
    .....
}

public aMethodSomewhereElse(){
   MyObj obj = ApplicationContextLocator.getApplicationContext().getBean(MyObj.class)
   assertNotNull(obj.getAField());
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the example, however this is to invasive for the existing code base. It IS possible to do this automatically via the @Configurable annotation using AspectJ as mentioned in my answer. I've edited with more info from the manual...  http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.0.RC2/reference/html/ch07s08.html

Answer (score 2):

Doing

```
MyObj obj = new MyObj()
```

means that obj is not managed by spring, so it will not do autowiring. 
Only way to do that is to obtain instance from an application context. For example:

```
ClassPathXmlApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("applicationContext.xml");
MyObj obj = context.getBean("myBean");
```